# Joins + group query works but throws error in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm working on an app with applicants and answers. Association:

```
applicant has_many :answers
```

I want to return only the applicants whose answers are not archived (in the answers table, archived: false). Currently, this is my query:

```
def index
    @super_admin = current_admin.super_admin
    @applicants = Applicant.joins(:answers)
        .where(answers: {archived: false})
        .group("applicant_id")
 end
```

The query runs fine, but I run into trouble in the view. I want to list the ids of all of the applicants returned by the query and link to that applicant's answers (as found by their answers.applicant_id). I added the .group in the index action because without it, I was getting every answer that wasn't archived (as opposed to every applicant whose answers weren't archived). So for applicant 4, I want to see one link '4' to lead to all of their answers.
Here's the link in the view:

```
<% @applicants.each do |a| %>
  <%= link_to "#{a.applicant_id}", "/admins/view/#{a.applicant_id}" %><br>
<% end %>
```

It throws this error:

```
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "applicants.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT "applicants".* FROM "applicants" INNER JOIN "answers"...
               ^
: SELECT "applicants".* FROM "applicants" INNER JOIN "answers" ON "answers"."applicant_id" = "applicants"."id" WHERE "answers"."archived" = $1 GROUP BY applicant_id
```

Any thoughts? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround (it's not as sleek as it could be, but it'll get me through a presentation tomorrow):

```
def index
      @super_admin = current_admin.super_admin
      @ids = Applicant.all
      @applicants = Applicant.joins(:answers)
        .where(answers: {archived: false})
        .group("applicant_id")
    end
```

view:

```
<% @ids.each do |a| %>
  <%= link_to "#{a.id}", "/admins/view/#{a.id}" %><br>
<% end %>
```